# My friend loses all his items upon disconnect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm hosting a minecraft server and it's just me and my friend playing. Every time he disconnects and comes back, all of his inventory is gone. However, the things in the chest remain there.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this? Can't even log out for the night and come back with everything. This issue doesn't happen with me, but only him. Again, we're the only two that are playing.

Comment: It sounds like the file used to record his player information isn't updating correctly.  When he comes back in, does it spawn him at the "inital spawn point" or does he spawn where he logged out?  Does he lose his exp if he has any?

Comment: You could try deleting his player file from your server folder.  When he comes back in it will be a fresh start, but if his player file was corrupt, this should resolve the issue.  You could also check the file properties on his file to make sure that it is not set to read only.  Finally, you might need to run your server "As Administrator" if the issue is related to file permissions.

Comment: Ahh. thanks guys. We were able to figure it out. When he logged in after disconnecting, he was using a different name than the one he previously logged out with. Using the same name on each login fixed the problem.

Comment: Mind if I ask how he was getting in with a different name?

Comment: @user1337 Likely a "cracked" server...

Comment: @NathanC Should we answer questions like "How do I work around an issue that comes up when trying to work with cracked games"?

Comment: @user1337 No...there's actually a specific close reason for this.

Comment: @lewlsaucengravy please post [your comment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161123/my-friend-loses-all-his-items-upon-disconnect#comment215913_161123) as an answer. This way it may help others with the same problem.

Comment: @NathanC people can have more than one Minecraft account, or play on another's computer under the other person's account.

Comment: @kotekzot I know, but from how it was explained this doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I see to possibilities that could cause that:

1. Your server switches between online and offline IDs
2. for some reason, your server does not write the player save files correctly

Check your server-log for the messages when your friend connects, you should see a message telling you the player-id of your friend.

Check your server-worlds directory, if you find files with that player-ID in your world save below the following folders.

- playerdata/
- stats/
- advancements/

in each of the folders you should find a file with the player-id of your friend.
Check if the "last modified" time changes, after your friend plays on your server.

If not you could try to run the `/save-all` command on your server before you close the server.

if the files still are not saved, check if your server has write permissions on this files, and if there is a "readonly" flag on the files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command:

```
/gamerule keepinventory true
```

Answer (score 0):

`/gamerule KeepInventory true` is for being killed, or dying. Maybe the file for their player got corrupted? If you can't fix it, report it to Mojang and until they fix it, put their items in a chest.

Answer (score -2):

This happens to me as well on mcpe. The best thing to do is obviously have him put his stuff in a chest. This may seem like a stupid answer but it is the only thing that works, as it seems.